# Tallying elements in a dataframe that meet a logic check

Tags: r, logic

I have a dataframe (studentData)

```
     StudentID   Freshmen    Sophomore      Lot200      Lot700
         001           1           0         200         000
         002           0           1         200         700
         003           1           0         200         000
```

I want a total of what the different academic years spent on parking. If Freshmen is 1 that is their year, similarity for Sophomore being 1.

Want to have this dataframe (costs)

```
  Freshmen        Sophomore 
  400             900
```

Tried

```
    if(length(which(studentData$Freshmen ==1))
       {
          costs$Freshmen <- studentData$Lot200 + studentData$Lot700
       }
```

But this results in returning TRUE for every entry and effectively adding every students expenditure on parking regardless of academic year. Any ideas how I might correct this?

Comment: Your `length(which(studentData$Freshmen ==1))` in the `if(` is always true, it's not a logical expression.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(lot_sum = Lot200 + Lot700,
         Freshmen = sum(lot_sum * Freshmen),
         Sophomore = sum(lot_sum * Sophomore)) %>% 
  distinct(Freshmen, Sophomore)
```

Which returns:

```
  Freshmen Sophomore
1      400       900
```

Comment: In my actual data frame I have student columns representing multiple years (Fresh2013, Soph2014, ect) and 8 different lot prices but I did not think that would make any difference for the code. Just expand on the idea. But when I run the code you suggested it returns a data frame with all NA values. Any thoughts what I might be missing?   `costs <-  academicMerge%>%
  mutate(lot_sum = Lot_1000 + Lot_1500 + Lot_1300 + Lot_700 + Lot_600 + Lot_400 + Lot_200,
         Fresh2017 = sum(lot_sum * Fresh2017),
         Soph2017 = sum(lot_sum * Soph2017)) %>%
  distinct(Fresh2017,Soph2017)`

Comment: You might be missing a `na.rm = TRUE` when using `sum`. Since you have multiple years and 8 different lot prices, my approach may be too much work. I will come back and update my answer once I’m back at my computer.

Comment: If you could give me your data with `dput` I would be happy to modify my answer. I'm thinking that `gather` from `tidyr` would make this a lot easier.

Comment: Next week when I am back in the office I will do just that. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like tyluRp, using `dplyr`. In base R, you can get the relevant quantities like so:

```
f = sum(studentData[studentData$Freshmen == 1,]$Lot200, 
        studentData[studentData$Freshmen == 1,]$Lot700)
s = sum(studentData[studentData$Sophomore == 1,]$Lot200, 
        studentData[studentData$Sophomore == 1,]$Lot700)
```

Then use `data.frame` to build the frame you want.

```
df = data.frame(Freshmen = f, Sophomore = s)
```

Tedious, and probably not even the best base R solution. But it's a more idiomatic way of getting the sums you want.

Comment: I like the idea of what you are going for here and as someone who has limited R experience using base packages is always nice, but it only returns a value of "NA_real_"

Comment: That's odd, it works for me on the sample. Maybe something to do with variable names.
Anyway if you're up for it I would definitely suggest dplyr, so maybe this is moot!